# Problem in converting Hexadecimal value to bigInteger

Tags: java

I have a string uniqueCode of length 16.

```
String uniqueCode = accountno + extracode;
```

accountno is of length 6 and extracode is populated in following way:

```
String extraCode = branch + loanCode + openingDateStr ;
BigInteger hexaCode = new BigInteger(extraCode); 
extraCode = hexaCode.toString(16); // hexa bit
```

Now i want to get back branch,loancode and openingdatestr from this uniquecode.
how to do this?

Comment: Why does this need to be a `BigInteger`?  You only normally convert to an integer if you want to perform some form of math operation on it.  If it's simply an identifier you can leave it as a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get back the original string from `extraCode` in hex:

```
BigInteger decCode = new BigInteger(extraCode, 16);
extraCode = decCode.toString(10);
```

Now you can extract the components from `extraCode` by their length. For instance, if `branch` has 6 digits and `loanCode` has 4 digits, you can do:

```
String branch = extraCode.substring(0, 6);
String loanCode = extraCode.substring(6, 10);
```